# Laravel 4 : Default route for route group

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to handle the default route of a route group, I have this but it doesn't work.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'administrator'), function() {

    Route::get('/', 'AdminUserController@getLogin');
    Route::controller('page', 'AdminPageController');
    Route::controller('user', 'AdminUserController');
    Route::controller('menu', 'AdminMenuController');

});
```

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you trying to do? What do you get?

Comment: If i try to get "localhost/public/administrator/", it goes to "localhost/administrator". I want to redirect "localhost/public/administrator/" to the login method of the AdminUserController. I hope it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out. You are missing a `uses`, and the second parameter should be an array.

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'AdminUserController@getLogin']);
```

Comment: If I go to http://localhost:8888/public/administrator/user/login, it is working, but it doesn't work when I only put http://localhost:8888/public/administrator/

Comment: Can you show your `AdminUserController@getLogin` method? Maybe you are just missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Yes I can, but I think this route doesn't work Route::get('/', 'AdminUserController@getLogin');

Comment: @bidou88 Just figured out the problem I think and edited my answer! Sorry, I'm a bit tired x)

Comment: I just tried with this route but it doesn't work neither :( I also tried to put Route::get('administrator', ['uses' => 'AdminUserController@getLogin']); outside of the route group, but it is always not working.

Comment: @bidou88 can we see your controller code? Have you try to put `dd('test');` in your method? Is it showing up?

Comment: `<?php

class AdminUserController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = "layouts.administrator";

        public function __construct() {

        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('getLogin', 'postSignin')));
        //$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
    }

    public function getLogin() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('administrator.login');
    }`