# Laravel default route for subdirectory in a route group with prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a route group for the prefix `admin`. I want that if the URL `http://www.example.com/admin/` is entered it by default loads the login page residing at `http://www.example.com/admin/login`. The login page is actually a controller, but I don't mind if the `admin/` redirects to `admin/login` or routes to its controller directly. From other answers I saw here it seems that redirection is better to make sure links are not messed up.

I have tried various solutions with both routing and redirection, including the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582354/laravel-4-default-route-for-route-group) but I am alwas getting Error 404. What is the recommended proper way to achieve this?

My route group looks like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'MyNamespace\Controllers\Admin'), function()
{    
    //the following work fine
    Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'AdminLoginController@showLogin'));
    Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'AdminLoginController@doLogin'));
    Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'AdminLoginController@doLogout'));

    //other resource routes for the respective admin pages
});
```

Outside the route group I added the following, so that even `http://www.example.com/admin` without the trailing slash goes to the login page, which works fine.

```
Route::get('admin', function() { return Redirect::to("admin/login"); });
```

The problem is with `http://www.example.com/admin/` that is giving Error 404. I tried all the following (separately obviously), and none works. All of them were inside the route group.

```
    Route::get('/', function() { return Redirect::to("admin/login"); });

    Route::get('', function() { return Redirect::to("admin/login"); });

    Route::get('/', function() { return Redirect::to("login"); });

    Route::get('', function() { return Redirect::to("login"); });

    Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'AdminLoginController@showLogin'));

    Route::get('', array('uses' => 'AdminLoginController@showLogin'));
```

I also tried this outside the route group:

```
    Route::get('admin/', function() { return Redirect::to("admin/login"); });
```

None of them work. What is the right way to set a default route for a route group with a prefix subdirectory?

Comment: When you tried `Route::get('/', function() { return Redirect::to("admin/login"); });` (which should is the correct one by the way) did you still have `Route::get('admin')` outside the route group?

Comment: I tried to remove the `Route::get('admin')` and add the `Route::get('/')` redirection and the effect remains the same. With the trailing slash it does not work, without it it works. There is something else I observed though, which might or might not be related. On my PC where I am testing, with the domain being `http://localhost/myapp/admin/`, for some reason it redirects to `http://localhost/admin/` omitting the `myapp` from the URL, ending up with an HTTP 404. While `http://localhost/myapp/admin` (without the trailing slash) redirects correctly to `http://localhost/myapp/admin/login`

Comment: I see. You should either use `http://localhost/myapp/public/admin` or set up a virtual host with document root pointing to the public directory. Then you can use it like `myapp.dev/admin`

Comment: Sorry I had forgot to mention that I had moved things out of `/public` to the root folder. I don't think that it is related though.

Comment: I discovered what was doing that weird redirection. I had this line in `.htaccess` which was generated by default by Laravel. `    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` I don't know what is the reason for it, but it was the cause of the redirection I had from `/myapp/admin/` to `/admin` causing the 404. I don't know why `/myapp` was being omitted, its the root folder of the application.

Comment: Great! Consider answering your question yourself so other people can profit :)

Comment: Thanks. However, I am wondering if this is the right way. That rule I presume is for a reason, and it seems pretty standard that the trailing slash is removed. But in this case it doesn't seem to make sense that way.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in `.htaccess`

so your server will redirect url's with trailing slashes to url without.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect everything to url without trailing slash

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:http]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ %{ENV:ps}://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

# pretty urls

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

by default laravel firstly did redirection, but later was removed.

Comment: Actually what I want is the opposite. If it does not have a trailing slash and is a folder I want to redirect it to have a trailing slash. But thanks for the pointer! In my `.htaccess` that Laravel generates I do actually have it, I commented it out and it now works!

Comment: if you want from "without trailing slash" To trailing slash, you will need to remove one line in .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`